# xaml user control object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I have a fairly simple Windows 8 XAML/C# UserControl:

```
  <UserControl
    x:Class="periodicTable.cell"
    x:Name="periodicTableCell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:periodicTable"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="100"
    d:DesignWidth="65">

<Grid Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="15"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Name="txtElementName"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="txtAtomicNumber"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" x:Name="txtSymbol"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" x:Name="txtAtomicWeight"/>
</Grid>
```

My code behind is:

```
namespace periodicTable
{
    public sealed partial class cell : UserControl
    {

        public string elementName { get; set; }
        public string atomicNumber { get; set; }
        public string symbol { get; set; }
        public string atomicWeight { get; set; }

        public cell()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.txtElementName.Text = elementName.ToString();
            this.txtAtomicNumber.Text = atomicNumber.ToString();
            this.txtAtomicWeight.Text = atomicWeight.ToString();
            this.txtSymbol.Text = symbol.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

When I add this control to my MainPage XAML:

```
xmlns:local="using:periodicTable"
```

Then when I try to add it to my grid:

```
<local:cell Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

I get an error stating: `object reference not set to an instance of an object`

I should note that I plan on reusing this user control in many rows and columns...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`elementName`, `atomicNumber`, `symbol` and `atomicWeight` appear not to be initialized.  Their values will be null and the `.ToString()` methods will fail.  Try initializing them to an empty string first.

Comment: Thanks.  That was the answer.